# How can I select bones with the Face mask activated in the weight paint mode

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I just updated my old blender to the new version 2.93 and I am trying to figure it out how to select bones on the weight paint mode while having the face mask activated.

In the previous blender version (2.83 and before) I could select the bones with the face mask activated by pressing <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> but now with the new keymap configuration the <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> combination only allows me to select the faces as I have the face mask activated.

It is pretty boring and annoying to keep activating and deactivating the facing mask to change the bones that I want to assign the paint.
Is there any solution to that? I couldn't find it anywhere.

PD: While I am without the face mask on, I can select the bones without any problem, but I really need to use the face mask because I have to paint some models with a lot of details.

[image]

Video reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os9lZUhpshI